# Question about time lag when resampling a dataframe from exel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have an exel sheet. The first column is time data that starts from 22:47:52 to 3:51:30 with 30 sec intervals. The second column is body temperature data. The part of the sheet is indicated in the image.
[link to the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HvODu_YWx1W2LoLDqYH0FFDyFnluCGq6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104151370755207623382&rtpof=true&sd=true)
I wanted to resample at 1 sec intervals starting at 22:48:00 and starting at the body temperature at 22:48:00. However, the output was resampled at 1 sec intervals starting at 00:00:00 and starting at the body temperature at 00:00:00.

My attempt has looked like this.

```
import pandas as pd

#path to the excel file
df = pd.read_excel(R"C:\Users\XXX.xlsx", sheet_name="XXX", usecols=[0, 1], index_col=[0], skiprows=[0, 1])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%H:%M:%S')

df_upsampled = df.resample("1s", origin='start').asfreq()
print(df_upsampled)
```

I got this output.

| date | body temp |
| --- | --- |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:00 | 36.23 |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:01 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:02 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:03 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:04 | NaN |
| ... | ... |
| 1900-01-01 23:59:26 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 23:59:27 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 23:59:28 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 23:59:29 | NaN |
| 1900-01-01 23:59:30 | 36.23 |

I also tried this code, but I got the same output.

```
import pandas as pd

#path to the excel file
df = pd.read_excel(R"C:\Users\XXX.xlsx", sheet_name="XXX", usecols=[0, 1], index_col=[0], skiprows=[0, 1])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%H:%M:%S')

start_time = pd.to_datetime("22:48:00", format='%H:%M:%S')

df_upsampled = df.resample("1s", origin=start_time).asfreq()
print(df_upsampled)
```

Could you give me any advice?

Comment: The dates in your xlsx file are probably in a different format. Please post a minimal reproducible example and don't use images of data or code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: `22:36:00` is not a date. Convert `to_timedelta` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Code**

we need minimal and reproducible example to answer. you must provide MRE from next time.

Here is a simplified representation of the dataframe you have:

```
time = ['23:59:58', '00:00:00', '00:00:02']
df = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 30], index=time, columns=['val1'])
```

df

```
            val1
23:59:58    10
00:00:00    20
00:00:02    30
```

---

**Issue**

The problems you encountered are as follows:

```
# To preserve the original dataframe, we practice on a copy named df1
df1 = df.copy()
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
out = df1.resample('1s').asfreq()
```

out

```
                    val1
2024-03-20 00:00:00 20.0
2024-03-20 00:00:01 NaN
2024-03-20 00:00:02 30.0
... ...
2024-03-20 23:59:56 NaN
2024-03-20 23:59:57 NaN
2024-03-20 23:59:58 10.0
86399 rows × 1 columns
```

By chking `df1`, the cause of the problem becomes clear. The same date was assigned to all data that only contains time. Please check the variable(here `df1`) if a problem occurs.

df1:

```
           val1
2024-03-20 23:59:58 10 <-- same date 
2024-03-20 00:00:00 20 <-- same date
2024-03-20 00:00:02 30 <-- same date
```

---

**Code**

Assigning different dates by setting the starting point to 00:00:00 should resolve the issue.

Here's an example of how to assign different dates:

```
# To preserve the original dataframe, we practice on a copy named df1
df1 = df.copy()

days = df1.index.to_series().str.split(':').str[0].astype('int').diff().lt(0).cumsum()
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index) + pd.to_timedelta(days, unit='D')
out = df1.resample('1s').asfreq()
```

out

```
                    val1
2024-03-20 23:59:58 10.0
2024-03-20 23:59:59 NaN
2024-03-21 00:00:00 20.0  <-- different date
2024-03-21 00:00:01 NaN
2024-03-21 00:00:02 30.0
```